# How HashMap stores Character keys? [Java]

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    map.put('A',1);
    map.put('a',1);
    map.put('f',5);
    map.put('t',5);
    map.put('m',4);
    map.put('r',3);
    System.out.println(map.keySet());   
}
```

Not able to understand why here the output is not in order, like:
[A,a,f,t,m,r]

instead, it is printing:
[A, a, r, t, f, m]

can anyone please explain?

Thank you :)

Comment: For sorting by natural order, use an implementation of `NavigableMap`/`SortedMap` such as `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap` makes no guarantees about the internal ordering, other than it being consistent - i.e., if you run the same program twice with the same JDK, you'll get the same order.

If you want a `HashMap` that preserves the order of insertion, you could use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).